# beginner: python namespace collision?

Tags: python, django, oop

Disclaimer: i am new to python but have drupal programming experience

I am reading the Definitive Guide to Django (http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter07/). After issuing

```
python manage.py startapp books
```

python creates the books package with views.py inside. Later in the tutorial, we enter the following into that views.py file:

```
# Create your forms here.
from django import forms
from django.forms import form_for_model
from models import Publisher

PublisherForm = forms.form_for_model(Publisher) 

TOPIC_CHOICES = (
    ('general', 'General enquiry'),
    ('bug', 'Bug report'),
    ('suggestion', 'Suggestion'),
)

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    topic = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    sender = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data.get('message', '')
        num_words = len(message.split())
        if num_words < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
        return
```

Unless I typed something wrong or misunderstood something (either is likely), we now (seemingly) have a collision between forms (books/forms.py) and django forms. So, which does Python refer to above in

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

Comment: Thank you both! form_for_model is now ModelForm and used differently from this tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

```
from django.forms import form_for_model
```

Really only pulls the name `form_for_model` into the module-global namespace, the already existing name `forms` is not affected. Even this:

```
import django.forms
```

would not be a problem, because it only makes the name available in its fully-qualified form, `django.forms` (which is unambigios and does not collide with `forms`).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike PHP, Python only imports into the *current* namespace, and each module is its own namespace; imports in other modules do not affect the current namespace, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Although this example does not cause a conflict as pointed out if there is a conflict you can use `from ____ import ___ as ___` to specify your own import name

http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import